# Tool for load-testing a website by requests per second

Tags: load-testing

I need a tool similar to ApacheBench but with the ability to specify the requests per second.

This tool needs to be runnable from the command line on Windows (any scripting languages, Ruby, Python etc are fine) and should be able to output results to file.

Bonus points if it can generate graphs or produce data files that can easily be graphed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter is what you are looking for!

It has good original documentation - http://jmeter.apache.org/ and a lot of other sourses, like [this](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase)

JMeter could be run from command line, it names [non gui-mode](http://blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode)

JMeter supports Javascript, Groovy, Java, Beanshell languages

And of course it could generate [graphs](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Graph_Results)

Answer (score 2):

Yes

JMeter is good tool to use and it has other features also(non-ui mode,lightweight,opensource etc.)

if you don't have licenses issue then probably go for Loadrunner which is very costly but has more features which are required for you (graphs,analysis)